# Meteor template function not rendering

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am trying to make a template render something on the client; I think I tried everything possible (apart from the correct thing apparently).

Html:

```
<head>
<title>Groups</title>
</head>


<body>
{{loginButtons}}      

{{>TplGroups}}
</body>

<template name="TplGroups">
groups found: {{ GroupCount }}
{{#each GetAllGroups}}
    <div> hello, {{name}}  group! </div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

serverStartup.js:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    Meteor.publish("GroupCount"), function()
        {
     return Groups.find({});
        }
  });
}
```

and the Groups.js collection which exposes the two methods GroupCount and GetAllGroups, which I want to access on client side:

```
var Groups = new Meteor.Collection("groups");
Groups.insert({name: "John"});


if(Meteor.is_client)
{
Meteor.subscribe("GetAllGroups");
Meteor.subscribe("GroupCount");

Template.TplGroup.GetAllGroups = function()
{
    return Groups.find({});
}

Template.TplGroup.GroupCount = function()
{
    return Groups.find().count();
}
}
```

I have removed "insecure" and "autopublish" packages. 
Where is my mistake? The two functions won't show on client.

Also what is the difference between declaring the functions as "publish" or declaring them as Template functions?

In browser console I get this:

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. (jquery.js)

Comment: You have a spelling error in your publish function. The function you defined should be the second parameter. Why did you put it outside the parenthesis? Also, note that you named that publish function `GroupsCount`, but what you are actually publishing are collection documents. Why such inconsistency?

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain what you mean by "the function you defined should be the second parameter"? A function is already as a second parameter (callback). What exactly am I supposed to be publishing here?

Comment: Please look into the answer.

Comment: Also a typo in the template name.  In the .html it is 'TplGroups' and in the .js it is 'TplGroup'.

Answer (score 0):

The publish method should look more or less like this

```
Meteor.publish("GetAllGroups", function () {
  return Groups.find({});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@apendua pointed to the right solution. I took your code and refactored it to make the solution a little clearer:

server.js:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // Publish groups
  Meteor.publish('groups', function() {
    return Groups.find();
  });
}
```

groups.js

```
Groups = new Meteor.Collection('groups');
Groups.insert({name: 'John'});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // Subscribe to groups
  Meteor.subscribe('groups');

  Template.TplGroup.GetAllGroups = function() {
    return Groups.find();
  }

  Template.TplGroup.GroupCount = function() {
    return Groups.find().count();
  }
}
```

It is enough to publish just groups. In your groups.js you try to subscribe to a publication that does not exist (GetAllGroups). Better to just publish and subscribe to simply 'groups' and return the groups count as described above. Also with a newer version of meteor you should use `Meteor.isClient` and not `Meteor.is_client`.

The jQuery error you described is not related to your code and appears (at least what I think) because of some issue with Meteor and/or jQuery itself. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

oups you just forgot "s" in your template name in your js file :

```
<template name="TplGroups"> <!-- what you wrote -->
```

and in your js you wrote :

```
Template.TplGroup.xxx
```

instead of :

```
Template.TplGroups.xxx
```